# Painting issues with TScaledLayout & custom styles

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, firemonkey-style

I'm experiencing painting issues when combining TScaledLayout and custom styles created from the bitmap style designer in fmx.

To demonstrate, I loaded the default custom style created by chosing "New style for VCL / FMX" -> "save as .style" in the bitmap style designer. I dropped several standard controls on some colored rectangles: The red & green ones on a TScaledLayout, the blue one directly on the form. As I stretch the form, colored lines appear on the controls on the ScaledLayout; the background is partially visible:

[image: paint issue with stretched controls]

If I size the form to exactly match the design-time dimensions, the lines disappear. That seems like a pretty significant issue, I certainly can't use those two together like that. Does anybody have an idea for a possible fix or workaround?

Comment: We've been seeing the same issue for many Delphi versions. It still exists in Delphi 10 Seattle.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known issue with scaling and bitmaps. See the Google+ discussion here - https://plus.google.com/+PaulThornton/posts/ACAHkJD3a84. I'll quote Marco Cantu's thoughts:

> I've found an internally reported issue of a similar case, but haven't
>   found one that matches this scenario. Certainly worth adding to quality
>   portal. Having said this, I fear that bitmap-based operations and
>   scaling don't really fit together very well, and it might be difficult
>   to have an all encompassing solution.
>
> Let me explain with an example. Take a button. This is painted by FMX
>   with 9 sections (borders, corners, central part) so that regardless of
>   the size the bitmap elements are stretched in one direction at most,
>   often just draw. Stretching a single bitmap for the button to the
>   target size would break anti-aliasing and create a blurred image when
>   using colors.
>
> This is example what happens with a ScaledLayout, given it takes the
>   complete final image and transforms it. ScaledLayout was originally
>   introduced with vector styles, and worked very well in that scenario.
>   With todays's bitmap styles things get a bit more complex.
>
> Regardless of this explanation of there the issue lies, I'd recommend
>   reporting it on QC, and I'll make sure it doesn't get closed as design
>   (it could naturally happen, this is how the system works) but that we
>   do some investigation to address the issue -- turning this into a
>   feature request.

Comment: I have found that this seems to be an issue with D2D, if I force using GDI+ (FMX.Types.GlobalUseDirect2D := false) it works fine. That's obviously not a very good solution though, since it sacrifices all the advantages of D2D. How does that align with Marco's explanation?